# Removing kitchen sink drain pipe from behind a wall

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

I'm replacing an old galvanized pipe from my kitchen drain to the basement.  The drain pipe corroded a couple feet down the line and is leaking.  I'd like to replace the entire run from the sink to the sewer with PVC.

The sink drain runs into a wall behind the cabinets and then straight down into the basement.

I don't know how to remove the section in the wall without cutting into the back of my fancy-ish new-ish cabinets and taking out drywall.

It looks like there's a nut right on the wall. If I remove that nut should I just be able to pull the pipe down into the basement?

[image: Under the sink, into the wall]

[image: From the wall, down to the basement]

Comment: Is the bottom picture form before the cabinets went in, or is that your current pipe access?

Comment: The bottom picture is from the basement looking up. The pipe that's coming down into the elbow is running in the wall behind my cabinet. This and the area in the first picture is my only access.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you intend to get the new pipe *in* after the old one comes out?

Comment: I was hoping installation was the reverse. But I just realized I think there's a vent going up through the wall to my roof that's fixed to this section too.  I'm starting to think I'll have to suck it up and cut into that wall.

Comment: It would be if it were just a straight pipe, but it's going to have a tail piece sticking out the side of it.

Comment: The end goal would be to cut at the galvanized that's between that Y and that floor joist and then in theory, pull the whole pipe downward and angle it upward it to fish that tail piece on the top out through the hole, but if there's a vent that kind of puts a kibosh on the whole plan.

Comment: I left enough galvanized exposed just a couple feet to the right of the bottom picture. I think my options are to either do it the right way (my original plan), or to just replace what I already have pulled out and leave this fight for another day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, if the drain is plumbed correctly, there is a vent pipe extending above the drain connection inside the wall. The connector is probably a wye, and there is no way to free the pipe without opening the wall.

Comment: I'm just going to run pvc between what's left of the galvanized today. It's not what I wanted but I'm not ready to open that wall up yet. And I want to do dishes today lol! I'm sure I'll be looking at this again in a couple of years when the rest of the galvanized starts to go but hopefully I can get some professional help ;)