# Can a corroded kitchen drain pipe stub going in wall be unscrewed? Is it just a nipple?

Tags: kitchens, drain, sink

My galvanized kitchen sink drain pipe is in a plaster wall behind a wood cabinet. The stub coming out of the wall into the cabinet is corroded (right at the wall) and the bottom of the stub (that I can feel in cabinet) seems like it is gone. It is leaking in basement directly under the stub. A hole in the stub had been temporarily repaired (years ago) in cabinet, but obviously the hole has gotten bigger and the pipe feels like the bottom has been eaten away completely.

[image: under cabinet showing where the pipe enters the wall]

I can see drain pipe in basement where it comes through the floor, but it is 1 foot or more to the left of where the stub comes out of wall upstairs.

[image: looking up from the basement]

[image: looking up from the basement with very small labels]

I am assuming the pipe 90s at some point before coming down through floor. In basement, drain pipe comes down to the right of vent pipe. Is the stub like a nipple that can be removed and replaced with channel locks or a wrench from inside cabinet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That should generally be a short piece going into an elbow or Sanitary "T" that looks something like this:

[image]

In a perfect world, you could potentially unscrew the "nipple" and replace it. You'll want to squirt some penetrating oil around the threads and be somewhat gentle when you try to unscrew the nipple so that you don't bust up the pipes in the wall too. It may take several times of applying oil, waiting for it to soak in, and trying to unscrew the nipple before it comes loose...if it comes loose.

The thing is, if the nipple is corroded enough to leak, the joint with the elbow/T is likely too corroded to easily disconnect them. The elbow/T and vertical pipe may be in similar condition as well considering it looks like there's been quite a bit of water dripping around in there for some time. (There seems to be water damage on the floorboards, etc.)

Sometimes the corrosion is the result of "gunk" that builds up in the drain pipe and causes the water/moisture to collect in horizontal runs and rust the pipes. They can also just corrode after years of service.

The best way to fix it would be to cut into the wall, remove the old iron pipes and replace them with PVC (or ABS if that's what they go for in your neighborhood) and tie into the iron pipes in basement with something like a no-hub/Fernco. That way you know the pipes in the wall are brand new and not likely to cause you trouble for years.

This [question maybe helpful](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/88301/25178).

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely try with the penetrating oil first. I'm trying to avoid cutting the back out of 2 cabinets. They are originals and I don't want to deal with that mess yet. The pipe had been leaking for quite awhile before it was temporarily fixed years ago & we never used the cabinet again. I checked under the sink regularly and did not see any water, so I think this bigger leak just happened.  I may get back to you if I have another question during my attempt to "fix." Thanks, again!!

Comment: I might suggest, @A.Kendall, you try "PB Blaster" as your penetrating oil. I've found it's far more efficient penetrating rust, oil & grease than WD-40 (the usual first thought for penetrating oil). I can't vouch for its ability to cut through water mineral deposits, but it does cut through iron (rust) deposits, so I'd guess it'll do a good job here.

Comment: I picked that up today at Home Depot. Thanks!

Comment: @FreeMan Good tip!